# how to redirect old html url to new php Url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, 301-redirect

How to  redirect old html page to new php page.
 I used this code but it redirecting with full file path.
 I'm using below code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ $1.php
```

Comment: Question is not much clear, i am trying to understand your requirement but there is possibility that i may understand it wrong . Please elaborate your question to get quick and appropriate solutions.

Comment: i have some old html url and i want to redirect it to new php url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but it redirecting with full file path

It will use the "full file path" if you specify a *relative substitution*. ie. a *substitution* that does not start with a slash (`/`) or scheme+host (absolute URL). In your example, using `.htaccess`, the captured backreference excludes the slash prefix on the URL-path. So, you need to explicitly include a slash prefix on the *substitution*. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ /$1.php
```

However, if you need an *external redirect* (as you are describing in your question) then you will also need to explicitly include the `R` (`redirect`) flag on the `RewriteRule`, otherwise you'll get an *internal rewrite* (the URL will not change - but your site may still work with the old `.html` URL).

And if you have other directives in your file, you may also need the `L` (`last`) flag to prevent further rewrites. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ /$1.php [R=302,L]
```

If this should be a redirect (as opposed to a rewrite) and this is a *permanent* change to your URL structure then change the `302` (temporary) to `301` (permanent) only when you are sure it's working OK. (`301`s are cached hard by the browser, so can make testing problematic.)